# SQL Oracle . View to count

Tags: view, count

I have a table:

```
JIRA_KEY   DATACENTER STATUS 
  1          US        CLOSED
  2         EM        CLOSED
  3         AP        CLOSED
  4         US        CLOSED
  5         EM        IN PROGRESS
  6         AP        CANCELLED
  7         US        IN PROGRESS
  8         US        CANCELLED
  9         AP        CANCELLED
  10        AP        IN PROGRESS
```

Expected Output:

Datacenter  TotalJiras  Closed  InProgress         Cancelled

EMEA         2           1            1                    0

APAC         4           1            1                    2

AMERICA      4           2           1                     1

I tried creating a view:

```
create or replace view VW_JIRA_STATUS_BK AS SELECT count(JIRA_KEY) JIRA , decode (substr(data_center,1,2),'EM', 'EMEA', 'AP', 'APAC', 'US', 'AMERICA') as REGION, status 
from hw_jira_status group by data_center , status;

select * from VW_JIRA_STATUS_BK
```

does not display the result as expected.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

`SELECT
        count(0) JIRA,
        AAA.REGION,
        AAA.status
    FROM (
        SELECT decode (substr(data_center,1,2),'EM', 'EMEA', 'AP', 'APAC', 'US', 'AMERICA') as REGION, status 
        from hw_jira_status 
    ) AAA
    group by AAA.REGION,
    AAA.status`

Updated SQL:

1. Create View V_AAA AS

   `SELECT
   count(0) JIRA,
   AAA.REGION,
   AAA.status
   FROM (
   SELECT decode (substr(data_center,1,2),'EM', 'EMEA', 'AP', 'APAC', 'US', 'AMERICA') as REGION, status 
   from hw_jira_status 
   ) AAA
   group by AAA.REGION,
   AAA.status`
2. Run

`SELECT
        V_AAA.REGION,
        V_AAA.status,
        (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM V_AAA V WHERE V.REGION = V_AAA.REGION AND V.status=V_AAA.status AND V.status='CLOSED') CLOSED,
        (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM V_AAA V WHERE V.REGION = V_AAA.REGION AND V.status=V_AAA.status AND V.status='IN PROGRESS') INPROGRESS,
        (SELECT COUNT(0) FROM V_AAA V WHERE V.REGION = V_AAA.REGION AND V.status=V_AAA.status AND V.status='CANCELLED') CANCELLED
    FROM V_AAA`

Comment: Just modified the requirement.